# Matrix reconstruction and multiplication in verilog

Tags: matrix, multidimensional-array, verilog, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to multiply two arrays of 16 bit fixed point numbers in verilog.  I have taken in 2 bit streams of 8 each of the fixed point number, reconstructed them into an 2-D array and am trying to multiply.  I get the errors that appear after the code.  I am aware the approach of reconstructing the array is going to be slow, but am out of ideas.  The issues i have ran into are not being able to take in 2-D arrays as inputs, and not being able to use variables in the indexing. If anyone could help me understand why i get these errors or suggest a better way to accomplish this task, it would be greatly appreciated.

FYI i have marked line 51....

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module Nueron(
    input wire clk,
    input wire [2:0] sel,
    input wire signed [383:0] z_in,
    input  wire signed [383:0] weights,
    output wire signed z_out
    );

    /***********signal declaration & constants*********************/
    //something signally
    reg signed [31:0] temp1  = 0;
    reg signed [31:0] temp2  = 0;
    reg [15:0] i = 0;
    reg signed [15:0] sum = 0;
    reg [15:0] bitCount = 0; 
    reg [15:0] wordCount = 0; 
    reg [15:0] z_Mat [23:0];
    reg [15:0] w_Mat [23:0];

    wire [4:0] countmax ;

    localparam nlSize = 24;
    localparam midSize = 8; 
    localparam outSize = 10;
    localparam fixed = 10;
    /*************body*********************************/
    always@(posedge clk) begin
        bitCount <= bitCount + 1;
        z_Mat[bitCount][wordCount] =  z_in[bitCount];
        w_Mat[bitCount][wordCount] = weights[bitCount];
        wordCount = (bitCount % 16 == 0) ? wordCount + 1 : wordCount;
    end

    always@(wordCount) begin
        temp1 <= z_Mat * w_Mat;   //This is line 51!!
    end

    always@(posedge clk) begin
        sum <= sum + (temp1 >>> 8);    
    end    

    assign countmax = (sel[2] == 1) ? nlSize : (sel[1] == 1)? midSize : outSize; 
    assign z_out = (i == countmax) ? sum : 0;

endmodule
```

[VRFC 10-394] cannot access memory z_Mat directly ["C:/Users/tomdi_000/capstone/capstone.srcs/sources_1/new/Nueron.v":51]

[VRFC 10-845] illegal operand for operator * ["C:/Users/tomdi_000/capstone/capstone.srcs/sources_1/new/Nueron.v":51]

[VRFC 10-395] cannot assign an unpacked type to a packed type ["C:/Users/tomdi_000/capstone/capstone.srcs/sources_1/new/Nueron.v":51]

[VRFC 10-1523] unpacked value/target cannot be used in assignment ["C:/Users/tomdi_000/capstone/capstone.srcs/sources_1/new/Nueron.v":51]

[VRFC 10-1040] module Nueron ignored due to previous errors ["C:/Users/tomdi_000/capstone/capstone.srcs/sources_1/new/Nueron.v":17]

Comment: I think you have found the problem already you cannot do matrix multiplication in verilog. You could put a loop around Line 51 to calculate each element of temp1 separately. But be warned multipliers are big and it is not standard practise to have many in parallel. TDM is often used to overclock the design and use a single multiplier over multiple clock cycles.

Comment: Im unclear on What TDM is.

Comment: Time Division Multiplex, it implies using the same hardware for different operations, by overclocking your design by four times on multiplier can be used for four multiplies.

Answer (score 0):

you can use array ports in systemVerilog, you will have the same code but change input ports to array and change file extension to .sv, please check the following code.

Some notes:

- Remainder is not synthesizable.
- Use reset to initialize counters.
- z_out must have size equal to (size of w_Mat + size of z_Mat + log2(number of accumulations)). .. I didn't change sizes in my code
- Remember to have a valid out to indicate accumulation finished and output is ready.

`timescale 1ns / 1ps

```
module Nueron(
    input wire clk,
    input wire nRst,// You will need a reset signal for initialization
    input wire [2:0] sel,
    input wire signed [15:0] z_Mat [23:0],
    input wire signed [15:0] w_Mat [23:0],
    output wire signed [31:0] z_out,
    output reg valid_out
    );

    /***********signal declaration & constants*********************/
    //something signally
    reg signed [31:0] temp1  = 0;
    reg signed [31:0] temp2  = 0;
    reg [15:0] i = 0;
    reg signed [15:0] sum = 0;
    reg [15:0] bitCount = 0; 
    reg [15:0] wordCount = 0; 
    reg valid_sum;
    wire [4:0] countmax ;

    localparam nlSize = 24;
    localparam midSize = 8; 
    localparam outSize = 10;
    localparam fixed = 10;
    /*************body*********************************/
//     always@(posedge clk) begin
//         bitCount <= bitCount + 1;
//         z_Mat[bitCount][wordCount] =  z_in[bitCount];
//         w_Mat[bitCount][wordCount] = weights[bitCount];
//         wordCount = (bitCount % 16 == 0) ? wordCount + 1 : wordCount; // remainder is not synthesizable
//     end

    always @(posedge clk) begin
      if(!nRst)// Active low synchrounous reset
    begin
      wordCount <=0;
      temp1 <=0;
      valid_sum <=0;
      z_out <=0;
    end
      else
    begin
      z_out <= z_out + temp1;
      valid_out <= valid_sum;
      if(wordCount == countmax-1)
        begin
          wordCount <= 0;
          temp1 <= z_Mat[wordCount] * w_Mat[wordCount];
          valid_sum <= 1;
        end
    end

    end


    assign countmax = (sel[2] == 1) ? nlSize : (sel[1] == 1)? midSize : outSize; 

endmodule
```

Comment: I thought the remainder operator is synthesizable if it is a multiple of 2?

Comment: *if it is a power of 2